# Create single method in Rails that handles multiple method names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to DRY-up the following code:

```
def is_user?
  is_role? ROLES[:user]
end

def is_mod?
  is_role? ROLES[:mod]
end

def is_admin?
  is_role? ROLES[:admin]
end

private

def is_role?(role)
  self.roles & role == role
end
```

Into a single function, yet still have the ability to call the function names as currently (`is_user?`, `is_mod?`, etc)

**UPDATE:**

Using Aetherus' answer below I created the following for managing user roles (where a user can have multiple roles):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Use bitwise values for more roles (double the previous values)
  ROLES = { user: 1, dummy: 2, mod: 4, admin: 8 } 

  # Add the desired role
  def add_role(role)
    self.roles |= ROLES[role]
  end
  # eg: add_role :admin

  # Removed the desired role
  def remove_role(role)
    self.roles &= ~ROLES[role]
  end

  # methods for each role (mod? admin? etc)
  ROLES.keys.each do |role|
    define_method("#{role}?") do
      self.roles & ROLES[role] == ROLES[role]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: ok now I see what you mean, that makes sense. Thanks for discussion :)

Comment: No problem at all :)

Comment: I would suggest changing "function" to "method" in your question.

Comment: @HunterStevens Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define multiple methods with one single ruby code block.

```
%w(user mod admin).each do |role|
  class_eval <<-RUBY, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
    def #{role}?
      role == '#{role}' && roles.include?('#{role}')
    end
  RUBY
end
```

Or a more clear way:

```
%w(user mod admin).each do |role|
  define_method("#{role}?") do
    self.role == role && roles.include?(role)
  end
end
```

By the way, in ruby, the `is_` prefix is not needed, since the trailing `?` tells the programmers that method returns a `true` or a `false`.

Comment: The second one is definitely more clearer to see what's going on. The first one would likely confuse others on the team (myself included a week from now :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice about not using `is_`. I've removed them from my code.

Answer (score 2):

You can go with [`method_missing`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing).

The simplest possible solution would be something like:

```
class Roles
  def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
    if /^is_(?<role_name>\w+)\?$/ =~ method_name
      is_role?(role_name.to_sym)
    else
      super
    end
  end

  private

  def is_role?(role_name)
    # just for demo purposes
    p "Checking #{role_name}"
  end
end

roles = Roles.new

roles.is_user?
roles.is_mod?
roles.is_admin?
```

In `method_missing` I'm trying to *catch* any method that is not implemented (please note, I removed the proper methods `is_user?`, `is_mod?` and `is_admin?`), later, I'm checking if the name of method is of *proper* format with Regex (`/^is_(?<role_name>\w+)\?$/`), and if it is, I'm reusing captured `role_name`.

*Slightly more restrictive `method_missing`*.

Problem with this approach is, it will accept any method call, like let's say `is_super_user?`. In some cases this might be desirable, sometimes not. If you would like to restrict it only to the 3 type of users you've mentioned, you can change the Regex to:

```
/^is_(user|mod|admin)\?$/
```

One last thing. When implementing `method_missing`, you should also take care about `respond_to_missing?`, which is quite crucial when you would like to assert if the object responds to those *magic methods*:

```
class Roles
  # ...
  def respond_to_missing?(method_name, include_private = false)
    /^is_(user|mod|admin)\?$/ =~ method_name
  end
end
```

With this in place, you are able to do:

```
roles = Roles.new

roles.respond_to? :is_admin? # => true
roles.respond_to? :is_super_user? # => false
```

Read more [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/always-define-respond-to-missing-when-overriding).

Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't like `method_missing`, because every time when a method call hits `method_missing`, it has already climbed the whole ancestors chain, at least once. This can be expensive.

Comment: Thanks @Aetherus, for your input! You are absolutely right - it might be expensive. However, `method_missing` lays as the most basic way of metaprogramming in ruby and as such I'm advertising it. Additionally, even if it can be expensive, I'm accepting the "cost" of it (as it gives so much flexibility) and I'm not refactoring it unless I hit some real performance issues. If it doesn't case any - usually I'm *ok* with it.

Comment: You're right. I also started with `method_missing`, and maybe it's the only way to meta programming features when the data is inadequate until runtime.

Answer (score 0):

@Jacob, if you use rails 4, you can use AR#enum feature (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html), no need to implement this by hands.

Comment: I tried using enums but wasn't able to use bitwise operations on it and each user can have multiple roles. Enums would only support one.